# AS3: cancel event

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

Let's say I want a Sprite to act as a button and I want this Sprite to be able to be disabled. Like so:

```
public class Button extends Sprite
{
    private var _disabled:Boolean = false;

    public function get disabled():Boolean
    {
        return _disabled;
    }

    public function set disabled( disable:Boolean ):void
    {
        _disabled = disable;
    }
}
```

and then somewhere I do:

```
var myButton:Button = new Button();
myButton.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, _someClickHandler );
```

then when I disable the button like so:

```
myButton.disabled = true;
```

... how can I make it, so that my Sprite doesn't fire of a MouseEvent.CLICK?
Or should I perhaps rethink my design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. 
`myButton.mouseEnabled = myButton.mouseChildren = false;`